How to move several parts of a multicam video and it's associated audio
What I need to do is to take a very complex multicam video and insert a new piece in the middle of it.
For instance, I have this project:

I need to move EVERYTHING from a certain point onward to the right:

And then I'm going to stick a new piece in that gap.  There are more synchronized pieces to the right of this screenshot, the whole video runs a little over an hour.
How would I do this and keep all the sync'd pieces intact?
